# Dynamic Padding (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, width, padding

```
$('#menu .sub-right').css( 'paddingLeft', $('#menu .sub-left').width() );
```

nor

```
$('#menu .sub-right').css({'padding-left': $('#menu .sub-left').width()});
```

...these work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes but - is now allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
$('#menu .sub-right').css( 'padding-left', $('#menu .sub-left').width()+"px" );
```

The [width function documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/) states:

> The difference between .css(width) and
>   .width()  is that the latter returns a
>   unit-less pixel value (for example,
>   400) while the former returns a value
>   with units intact (for example,
>   400px). The .width() method is
>   recommended when an element's width
>   needs to be used in a mathematical
>   calculation.

But since CSS expects ###px, you can use the above code or this code:

```
$('#menu .sub-right').css( 'padding-left', $('#menu .sub-left').css('width') );
```

Either one should work.